# Do not Delete worksheets if it is in array

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim L As Double
Dim Workings() As Variant

Workings = Array("Due SO not Billed", "Working Paper", "Ageing Over 14 Days")

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For L = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(L).Name <> Workings Then
    Worksheets(L).Delete
    Exit For
    End If
Next L

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0
```

I tried writing above code. The purpose is I have 10 worksheets in a workbook but final output requires only 3 sheets and I want to delete the rest of the worksheets. I tried above code with array and whatever name I gave in the array should be saved and all other remaining sheets should be be deleted. I'm getting type mismatch error. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Match` to test whether the worksheet's `Name` is in the array:

```
Dim Workings() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet

Workings = Array("Due SO not Billed", "Working Paper", "Ageing Over 14 Days")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Workings, False)) Then
        ws.Delete
    End If
Next    
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: "Stealing" my match ? ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado "Borrowing", you can have it back any time you want it!

Answer (score 2):

Smells like homework. It's not working because the Workings variable is an array while the other is a string, they are different types. To test if a string is inside an array do

```
 If Not IsInArray(Worksheets(L).Name, Workings)
 Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
   IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
 End Function
```

Comment: Ah. Good old VBA. With it's complete non-applicability to the real world except through legacy projects and microsoft access.

Comment: IsInArray is a function in VBA @YowE3K LOL. Yeah it's weird VBA is even taught in schools or anything.

Comment: As it turns out, it's just part of an API I've used, I included my code. I apologize

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA Filter function gives you the added benefit of comparing Text.  In this way you do not have to be concerned with capitalization.

```
Sub DeleteWorksheets()
    Dim Workings() As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Workings = Array("Due SO not Billed", "Working Paper", "Ageing Over 14 Days")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In Worksheets

        If UBound(Filter(Workings, ws.Name, True, vbTextCompare)) = -1 Then ws.Delete

    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my `valueInArray` function:

```
Public Function valueInArray(myValue As Variant, myArray As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim cnt As Long

    For cnt = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        If CStr(myValue) = CStr(myArray(cnt)) Then
            valueInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cnt

End Function
```

It is quite a lot of code and it loops, but it works. Plus, it works ok for both integers and strings.